# How can I dismiss the media picker after I select two songs?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want to be able to pick two songs from my music library and dismiss the picker after I select the songs. Right now I have to press the done button to dismiss it. How would I be able to do that?

```
//MEDIAPLAYER---------------------------------------------------------------
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

if mediaItemCollection.items.count > 1 {
let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem
music = aMediaItem
NSLog("\(aMediaItem.title)selected")

let url: NSURL = (music.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!

    do {
        musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        return
}
}

if mediaItemCollection.items.count > 1 {

    let aMediaItem2 = mediaItemCollection.items[1] as MPMediaItem
    music2 = aMediaItem2
    NSLog("\(aMediaItem2.title)selected")
    let url2: NSURL = (music2.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!

    do {
        musicPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url2)


    } catch {

        return
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not put a count in the 'didPickMediaItems ' if the count it 2 dismiss the controller like you are doing from the done button ?

Comment: I didnt put count for the done button.

Comment: Yes , i know, can you put your done button code in the sample code shown above?

Comment: Im using the delegate func mediaPickerDidCancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: MPMediaPickerController don't provide any default method by which you can directly close the controller based on your requirement

For customisation in the the Song selection you can use `MPMediaQuery` and `MPMediaItem` which will return you the song listing with details. you can show that in your UITableView/UICollectionView and implement your customise logic

---

**Old Code:**
This can only be used if you want to do some processing after done is pressed manually

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
         //rest of your code
        if mediaItemCollection.items.count == 2 {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
        }
        //rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't dismiss on its own after I pick two songs. I have to still press the done button.

Comment: @coding22, how you have shown the MPMediaPickerController ? self.presentViewController ?

Comment: I'm in SpriteKit so I had to use self.view.window.rootviewcontroller.presentvieecontroller

Comment: @coding22 ok, can you debug if you code come in the dismiss condition as when i present like you have written it's working for me in normal application

Comment: Does it dismiss on its own when you pick the two songs? For me I have to press done when I pick the two songs.

Comment: @coding22, for now, i am checking in simulator by calling this method after some seconds after opening the picker and it's dismiss, still i will check in real device tomorrow if that is having any specific issue

Comment: @coding22 ,I have check this code in device  as didPickMediaItems only call when done button is pressed , this code will not work